# C2196 case value already used for cases with nonenglish characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When compile my source code on different machine suddenly got C2196 for subsequent switch cases with non english letters in it. I use Win10 21H1 19043.1586, MS VC 2017 compiler 15.9.45. Project use a lot of compiler options so I won't bloat here, the only may seem coherent ar /Zc:wchar_t and std:c++17.
The code compiles on the other "same" win10+vs2017 installation.

Code is like

```
char16_t ch = ...

switch(ch) {
  case u'â':
  case u'ê':
  case u'î':
  case u'ô':
  case u'û':
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally narrow down a problem and found a "tiny" difference in the language configuration. In Region Settings of the second computer there was a tick set in "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support".

Uncheck it and restart solves the problem.
[image]

Don't have time to investigate further. Any comments and clarification would be highly appreciated!